# CSS flexbox width 100% Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I'm having an issue with this scenario in Firefox. #pager takes the width of its children. However, in Chrome, it takes the width of its parent. How can I make #item-list respect the width of its parent in Firefox?

take a look! https://jsfiddle.net/owmpatbh/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="content">
        <p id="stuff">blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah</p>            
      </div>
      <div id="pager">
          <div id="item-list">
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {


 display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 0.25;
  border:3px solid green;
  min-height: 200px; 
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex: .75;
  flex-direction: column;
  border:3px solid orange;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0.85;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

#pager {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  flex: 0.15;
}

#item-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

#stuff {
    height: 200px;
}

*{
    margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to like the fixed 200px width for some reason. not sure why yet

Comment: Since you're using flex, you shouldn't need to use `width: 100%` anywhere. Taking it out doesn't break anything in Chrome, nor make anything worse in firefox. Firefox seems to want a fixed width for `#item-list`, but again, I'm not sure why. It doesn't seem to want to handle the inline-block children properly (or maybe the behavior isn't well defined yet?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

firefox has problems with the width of the object `#item-list`. I can not think of anything else then this is a bug, at least chrome is less picky on the width. So, what you'll have to do is give it a fixed width as said by redbmk. So here is the solution:

set the `#item-list` position to `absolute` and give it a `width` of `100%` (in the example minus the border of the divs).

```
#pager {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  height:246px;
}

#item-list {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 9px);
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I also changed some small(not really important things) in your code.

see it here:

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owmpatbh/3/)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

here is a working link https://jsfiddle.net/ymvmf6zz/1/

apparently explicitly setting the width on #sidebar and #main made it work.

```
#sidebar{
    width: 25%;
}
#main{
    width: 75%;
}
```