# flex item width larger than image contained inside

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have a flex item div to have the same dimensions as its contained image, but it seems the div doesn't know about the image's scaled size and always has the same width as the full sized image, resulting in a visible border on the right side.

I understand that if I remove the `.flex-top` div everything works as expected, because the `.flex-bottom` div and its parents have an height of 100%. Once the top div is back, however, it still keeps the same width, as if flex-grow had no effect on its computed height.

I'm pretty sure the problem lies in `.flex-bottom`'s height 100% but can't think of a workaround.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: white;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.flex-top {
  flex: 2;
  background: salmon;
}

.flex-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  align-self: center;
  background: seagreen;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-top">
      <p>Hello, I take 2/3 of the page</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-bottom">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: note that this only happen in Firefox. In chrome your code works fine

Comment: Oh right, thanks, didn't even notice.But in Chrome, if you try to resize the window vertically, there's this weird bug where the div doesn't follow the image's width and the image is not centered anymore. No idea what happens here.

Comment: it's a complex case of cyclic calculation. Trying to find a related question

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113733/css-flexbox-width-100-firefox

Comment: here is a related question (almost a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/a/58905047/8620333 ... the first part deals with another issue but at the end you have examples with image and explanation about the difference and how to make sure it's *almost* the same cross browser

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried the solution provided in your link but it still resizes weirdly. I made a jsfiddle of my changes: https://jsfiddle.net/k1zodwba/ . Did I do something wrong ? @UtsavPatel thank you as well, works great on Firefox but images are not centered on Chrome. How could I make that work ?